# "show databases" in HQL Hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate, hql

I am trying to list all databases in MySQL using Hibernate. But I am getting below error.

```
Nov 24, 2016 11:50:27 AM org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.ErrorCounter reportError
ERROR: line 1:1: unexpected token: show
Nov 24, 2016 11:50:27 AM org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.ErrorCounter reportError
ERROR: line 1:1: unexpected token: show
line 1:1: unexpected token: show
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlBaseParser.statement(HqlBaseParser.java:191)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.parse(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:295)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.doCompile(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:203)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.compile(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:158)
    at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.HQLQueryPlan.<init>(HQLQueryPlan.java:126)
    at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.HQLQueryPlan.<init>(HQLQueryPlan.java:88)
    at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.QueryPlanCache.getHQLQueryPlan(QueryPlanCache.java:190)
    at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSessionImpl.getHQLQueryPlan(AbstractSessionImpl.java:301)
    at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSessionImpl.createQuery(AbstractSessionImpl.java:236)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.createQuery(SessionImpl.java:1796)
    at TestHibernate.main(TestHibernate.java:40)
```

## Below is my code

```
    Configuration cfgObj = new Configuration();
    cfgObj.configure("MySQLhibernate.cfg.xml");
    servcRegObj = (ServiceRegistry) new StandardServiceRegistryBuilder().applySettings(cfgObj.getProperties()).build();
    SessionFactory sfObj = cfgObj.buildSessionFactory(servcRegObj);

    Session session = sfObj.openSession();
    BSCTable bscTblObj = new BSCTable();

    Query qry = session.createQuery("show databases");
    List<Object> databaseList = qry.list();
    for(Object object : databaseList)
    {
        System.out.println(object);
    }
    session.close();
    sfObj.close();
```

Comment: `show databases` is not valid HQL. Just run a vendor-specific query like that against the jdbc object directly. Hibernate is not the silver bullet for interacting with databases in every possible way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`show databases` is not a valid JPQL statement and dependent on the database you are using. You can use a native query
    `session.createSQLQuery(...)`
to talk to the database directly, but in this case, you will lose the Hibernate advantage of database independent implementation.